# Define variables in an implicit way

Tags: r, variables

I wanted to know how I can define variables in an implicit way in R.

For example, let's assume I have z<-0.5 and x<-2, I want to define y such that the following holds: z=beta(x,y).

Obviously, if I enter `z<-beta(x,y)`, I have the following error `Error in beta(x, y) : object 'y' not found`.

I tried to find a solution in google but strangely I didn't find anything.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make a function? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You may want to have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Parameter_estimation and possibly at `?mle`

Comment: Well, I have the values for x and z and I need the value for y such that the condition is respected. 
The problem is that I cannot put y alone in the left hand side so I cannot define y in the "normal way", i.e. y<-

My actual equation is way more complicated than that but the idea is the same.

The Beta function is only an example. I don't want to estimate it. I  want to solve the equation in order to get the value of y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example you could use `uniroot` to find the value of y:

```
(y <- uniroot(function(y) beta(x,y)-z, interval=c(0,100)))
$root
[1] 1

$f.root
[1] -1.08689e-07

$iter
[1] 13

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05

beta(x,y$root)==z
[1] FALSE
all.equal(beta(x,y$root),z, tol=1e-5)
[1] TRUE
beta(x,1)==z
[1] TRUE
```

However this relies on a number of assumptions such as there only being one value to satisfy the equation and you being able to give it a sensible interval. In general your function may not admit solutions, and it may be slow to compute if you need to calculate a large number of y values. You also need to consider that a numerical solution may not be exact, so comparisons will need to be made with care.